# I'm not sure if this is a restrictive or a non-restrictive clause (using the word 'whilst')

Tags: punctuation, tenses, non-restrictive

I've been tasked with editing a new hire's bio, and I've been stumped by  comma. For context, the intern is writing about how they found the company's job ad. They are currently still studying at university. Here's the original:

> I was looking to gain some work experience **, whilst** I’m studying,
> and I happened upon a [company name] post advertising an internship
> position.

Here's my potential edit (without the comma):

> I was looking to gain some work experience whilst I’m studying, and I
> happened upon a [company name] post advertising an internship position.

Am I overthinking this? Is there no need to remove the comma?

Edit: I forgot to specify that this is UK English.

Comment: Whilst is formal for AmE, bit I agree that the comma doesn’t help. While is enough.

Comment: _Whilst_ introduces a _temporal clause_ not a _restrictive/non-restrictive clause_. I agree with Xanne that _while_ is preferable and the comma better omitted.

Comment: Many thanks @Xanne and Shoe. I've taken your advice about the comma and replacing the word 'whilst'.